# Adding subscripts or superscripts into bar chart using ArcMap

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, chart

Is it possible to add subscripts or superscripts into a bar chart axis making in ArcMap?

I know that for labels the code is `<sup>2</sup>` or with sub. I'm using in the label bar chart but it didn't work.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can certainly put as superscript 2 in the title using the Windows character map application with a system font. A subscript does not exist in that font, but does in say Calibri, but that appears not to work in ArcMap.

That said have you used the [Advanced Properties](https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/map/graphs/changing-the-text-and-style-of-titles.htm), may be you can access the sub\sup script that way?

I can't verify this as ESRI have broken this dialog in 10.7 (which is what I have) and don't appear to have fixed it for that version... Rubbish really.

Comment: I already looked up in Advanced Properties, but I didn't get any tool to sub/sup script. Well, thank you!